# spark how to indicate to driver node one item is done?

Tags: apache-spark, concurrency

```
//work split
spark.parallelize(1, 10k).map(item => doTask(i)).collect()
```

where I have some logging to do in database for doTask(i). it's uneasy to serialize the dbManager and send to worker node. is there anyway for spark to indicate back to driver node that taskI is done and then do the logging on driver node ?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of three options:

#### map

Within the [map](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#map%5BU%5D(f:T=%3EU)(implicitevidence$3:scala.reflect.ClassTag%5BU%5D):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD%5BU%5D) function (in the example within the method `doTask`) you could instantiate the `dbManager` and run the logging code. The `dbManager` will be created on the executor/worker nodes.  However, this option will result in a very bad performance of the Spark job as there will be one db connection created per element of the `rdd`.

#### mapPartitions

Using [mapPartitions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#mapPartitions%5BU%5D(f:Iterator%5BT%5D=%3EIterator%5BU%5D,preservesPartitioning:Boolean)(implicitevidence$6:scala.reflect.ClassTag%5BU%5D):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD%5BU%5D) only one `dbManager` per partition of the `rdd` will be created on the executor/worker nodes. Actually, creating a db connection within a Spark task is the typical use case for [mapPartitions](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-map-vs-mappartitions-transformation/).

```scala
val result = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(1 to 10000).mapPartitions(it => {
  //initalize and use database connection here
  for( item <- it) yield {
    doTask(item)
  }
}).collect()
```

Depending on the size of the rdd and the number of partitions (or the possibility to find a good [partitioner](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#partitioner:Option%5Borg.apache.spark.Partitioner%5D)) this option will provide good performance characteristics.

#### Kafka or similar

The third option would be to use a messaging technique outside of Spark, for example [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/).

Answer (score 0):

The forth, and probably better option is to extend [`org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListener`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/scheduler/SparkListener.html) and provide implementation of `onTaskEnd` method according to your needs.

> **onTaskEnd**
>
> public void onTaskEnd(SparkListenerTaskEnd taskEnd)
>
> Description copied from interface: SparkListenerInterface
> Called when a task ends
>
> Specified by: onTaskEnd in interface SparkListenerInterface
>
> Parameters: taskEnd - (undocumented)

Then register this listener with SparkContext using [`addSparkListener`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#addSparkListener-org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerInterface-) in order for it to receive the task completion details.